# Is there a definitive list of airflow permissions?

Tags: airflow

I am investigating RBAC permissions in Apache Airflow which has led me to read [Security > RPAC UI Security](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html#rbac-ui-security). It talks about various permissions that are granted in the various roles however I am interested in defining more granular custom roles. In order to do that it would be useful to see a definitive list of all permissions that can be granted and get a description of each of them. Some of them are obvious (e.g. can_add, can_edit, can_delete) but others less so (e.g. can_task, can_code)

Does anyone know if a definitive list of permissions, with descriptions, exists?

Comment: Not sure. But you know there's the Airflow Summit starting today.. and running for next 2 weeks.. https://airflowsummit.org/ - Maybe something you could ask then - first one starts in about 3.5hrs time. https://airflowsummit.org/sessions/run-airflow-dags-secure-way/

Comment: https://www.manning.com/books/data-pipelines-with-apache-airflow - There's likely an upcoming chapter in this book too.

Comment: The folks at EA have also  implemented a multi tenancy architecture. For more info check the Airflow youtube channel in coming weeks  EA/Preethi Ganeshan

Comment: Also https://www.terraform.io/ Michael Hewitt talk (with Kubernetes)

Comment: https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer-fab-securitymanager

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the definitive source, [the `airflow/www/security.py` file seems to be the place](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c420dbd6e13e17867eb4ccc4271b37966310ac0f/airflow/www/security.py#L87-L182). As for descriptions and such you might have to wait for someone to come along and type up their usages but most seem pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Yeah I'd come to the same conclusion upon stumbling across that file. Most of them are self-explanatory, though some are still a little ambiguous.